# Retrieve part from an Array of Document

Tags: php, mongodb

I am building a project using mongodb and php, so my database contains the following record.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$id": "515bb7e2a00b2add0b000001"
    },
    "user_id": "user_8888",
    "events": {
        "common test I": {
            "subject": "common test I",
            "start_date": "04/14/2013",
            "start_time": "8.00 AM",
            "end_date": "04/14/2013",
            "end_time": "10.30 AM",
            "all_day_event": "false",
            "discription": "no discription",
            "location": "STC",
            "private": "false",
            "time_zone": "IST",
            "alarm": "true",
            "alarm_threshold": "5",
            "status": "true"
        }
    }
}
```

So only using query, how I retrieve "common test I" event from the record. The result should be:

```
{
    "subject": "common test I",
    "start_date": "04/14/2013",
    "start_time": "8.00 AM",
    "end_date": "04/14/2013",
    "end_time": "10.30 AM",
    "all_day_event": "false",
    "discription": "no discription",
    "location": "STC",
    "private": "false",
    "time_zone": "IST",
    "alarm": "true",
    "alarm_threshold": "5",
    "status": "true"
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Thanks for the editing , otherwise it looked all different and i was so confuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.collection.find({},{"events.common test I":1,_id:0})`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which fields of the document you want to retrieve in the find method.

See [PHP.net Reference Manual for MongoCollection::find](http://php.net/manual/de/mongocollection.find.php).

Something like

```
$collection->find(array(), array('events.common test I'=>true));
```

Note that "The _id field is always returned."

Although I would suggest not to use spaces in object keys / field names.

Comment: can I search that document using 'start_date' without using key I mean 'common test I'

Comment: It would be easier if you used a set instead of an associative array for the events (e.g. `{events: [ { start_date:'', ...}, { start_date:'' , ...} ] }`)

Then try `find(array('events.$.start_date'=>'04/14/2013'))`

You might also be able to achieve this using the [elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/) operator.